# MYSQL Flush Tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I typed 'flush tables' on my shared hosting account at my phpmyadmin. The reason I did this is to see how fast my queries executed when they were not cached. Now when I try to execute any query after typing in the query box, it gives a strange error as such:

```
import.php: Missing parameter: import_type
import.php: Missing parameter: format
```

Also using the MYSQL Administrator, i connected to my hosted database. Trying to execute a query gives me

```
Got error 28 from storage engine
```

Thanking you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How do you call your import.php script? Where is this script called from?

This "`Got error 28 from storage engine`" translates into "`Error code 28: No space left on device`" – meaning a disk partition on your server's hard disk ran out of free disk space or mysql is running out of space for it's db file

Comment: Worth adding that if you want to find out about odd error codes like #28 then run the command `perror` with the error code. E.g. `perror 28` on the server and it should explain what it means.

Comment: In some cases on shared hosting servers, the DB engine/disk might have space left but your DB quote could have been exceeded. I've seen db quotes done via user quotas which has caused similar errors.